# How can I disassemble a multi-tool with no screws on it?

Tags: diy, knives

I have a multi-tool and I want to disassemble it – not for any repairing just to take it apart and take the blade for other uses – but it has no screws.

How can I disassemble it? (See image below)

[image: img]

Comment: This is not designed to be disassembled for maintenance. If it is faulty, just replace it.

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh I said multi-tool, just add swiss army knife for explaining cause sometimes I'll met someone who don't know what multi-tool mean, I'll remove it :)

Comment: Hi Munucial. Can you clarify why you want to disassemble this tool? The answers are assuming it's for the purpose of doing something and then putting it back together? Is that the case? Would you please edit that right into the text? Thanks!

Comment: This question got me wondering, why you would want to disassemble a multi tool and what other purpose you might use the blade for.  So I asked this new question [Can I use the blade of an multi tool as a spear point?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17992)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tool pictured is riveted together with [solid rivets.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rivet#Solid/round_head_rivets)  It is not designed to be repaired, as mentioned in a comment, if it is not working correctly it should be disposed of and replaced.

It is possible to use a grinder to remove the flared head of the rivet and then punch it out.  Alternately you can drill out the rivet, by drilling a hole in the exact center of the rivet.  While both of these approaches theoretically allow for reassembly, they will almost certainly damage the tools body to some extent.

Re-assembly would require either a precision sized high grade bolt OR equipment to replace a solid rivet (**This is NOT a [blind/pop rivet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rivet#Blind_rivets)**). As this is a solid rivet, rivet replacements require tools not generally found in the home tool shop or home store. Bolts in this size from a home supply store will not be strong enough to handle the load.  Bolts have a [strength grade](https://www.boltdepot.com/fastener-information/materials-and-grades/bolt-grade-chart.aspx), small bolts from the home supply store are not designed for tool quality use.

Attempts to repair the tool pictured will cost more than a replacement tool, and most likely will leave you with a tool that is NOT safe to use.

Comment: I don't know about this tool but M6 bolts are common for bolted multi tools. Even the cheapest M6s would be strong enough. Some of the rivets can get down to around 2mm and I wouldn't trust an M2 to hold a tool together

Answer (score 6):

Disassembly is the easy part.  Drill out the rivets.

Reassembly will be a big problem.