# Can I use the blade of a multi tool as a spear point?

Tags: survival, knives, spears

A recent question [asks about disassembling a multi tool](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17965) pictured below.

We have an existing question [How do you fashion a spear with a fixed blade](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1924). All of the blades pictured are long handled and/or have a long tang. A long tang provides a solid mounting point as shown in [the accepted answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5352).

Half a dozen multi tool blades would be a small and light addition to my survival gear.  If they were all potential spears it could make a huge difference in a survival scenario, and would keep my primary long handled knife from being at risk of loss or damage in a spearing event.

Can I use the blade of a multi tool as an effective spear point?  If so, how would I attach it?

[image: img]

Comment: `keep my [...] knife from being at risk of loss or damage in a spearing event` - does that happen to you often? "Spearing events?"

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you could if you can get the multitool apart, although it won't be the easiest thing in the world. and it won't be as stable as a traditional arrow head or spear point.

Basically, you want a straight-ish branch about the same thickness as the blade you are intending to use. Use your narrowest blade or punch type blade to bore a hole in the branch, take the multi apart, then either use the cotter pin from the multi or a smaller branch pounded into the hole to secure the blade. You will want to place the hole down from the end of the branch 1" or so, and then also split the branch in the middle to accommodate the blad. You'll need to wrap it with something to bind it, and since it only has a single hinge point, it will be apt to collapse.

What I would recommend as an alternative, is a set of throwing knives. A lot of varieties are not the greatest for throwing, but for the weight, you can pack three for very little overhead. Many varieties have holes bored in the handle for weight distribution, as seen here:

[image]

That also gives you spares, and if you get a decent set, then you also have a ranged recoverable weapon as well.